# Viewport meta tag in iframe

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, iframe, viewport

I have a html page that has a viewport meta tag.
I'm viewing the page on iPad and it displays with the right viewport.
If I open another page with no viewport tag in it which contains an iFrame that point to my page the viewport tag has no effect.

Is this the correct behaviour?
Is there a way to have the viewport tag working from within an iframe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because of security issues iframe content cannot "leak" onto the parent page, meta tags have to be in the original page code.

Comment: Do you mean that if I have a viewport of  lets say 600px width in the outside page, that width will be applied to the iframe content as well?

Comment: Kinda, If the iframe is for example 700px big and viewport is 600px big it will cut off the 100px from the iframe

Comment: can we prevent the viewport width to apply on iframe ?